# How to align values in table according to the \pm and point?

Tags: tables

```
{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
F&                      R         \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

42.34 \pd 0.16 & 42.34 \pd 0.16          \\
424.34 \pd 0.16          &   5542.34 \pd 50.16  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
21.9            &   20.8            \\
9.1             &   8.7             \\

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
```

The code after your help:

```
{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{table*}
\caption[]{Solution in \phoebe for different input photometry files, based on photometric data sets and Gaussian RVs for
the primary}\label{PHOEB}
\begin{flushleft}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}S[table-format = 3.3(3)]}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Data&                       B.R         &   B.B         &   A            &  B            &  K + K    &  K + L +\\&&&&&&+ S \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

Co $ \chi^2$   &    3.758           &   1.721           &   76.945          &   1.008           &   11.389          &   4.067               \\
$b$                  &   42.34 \pd 0.16  &  41.63 \pd 0.37  &   41.56 \pd 0.47  &   40.71 \pd 0.21  &   41.91 \pd 0.18  &   41.81 \pd 0.43      \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
A           &   21.9            &   20.8            &   20.7            &   19.4            &   21.1            &   21.1                \\
B           &   9.1             &   8.7             &   8.6             &   8.1             &   8.8             &   8.8                 \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
The rms errors of the last two quoted digits are given in brackets after the respective value. 
\end{flushleft}
\end{table*}
}
```

Comment: Please tell us how `\pd` is defined. Is it maybe just a mis-spelling of `\pm`?

Answer (score 4):

Using `siunitx`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{table}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 3.2(3)]S[table-format = 4.2(4)]}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
F&                      R         \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

42.34 \pm 0.16 & 42.34 \pm 0.16          \\
424.34 \pm 0.16          &   5542.34 \pm 50.16  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
21.9            &   20.8            \\
9.1             &   8.7             \\

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

I took a liberty and add image of table produced with above code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you and what does this error means? `siunitx error: "invalid-number"!!!`

Comment: The example runs as-is: please say what you've changed

Comment: I edded the code after your help to my question

Answer (score 3):

I would also use `siunitx`  and exploit its option `separate-uncertainty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         group-four-digits}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 3.2(3)]
                S[table-format = 4.2(4)]}
\hline\hline
F           & R                     \\
\hline
 42.34(16)  &   42.34(16)           \\
424.34(16)  & 5542.34(5016)         \\
\hline
21.9        &   20.8                \\
 9.1        &    8.7                \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Addendum

It seems that you looking for something like this:

[image]

Above table is composed with two successive tables and manual tweaks for position of the column header. From comment of Barbara Beeton follows that this is somewhere already settled, but I didn't find this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         table-column-width=6em}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 3.2(3)]
                S[table-format = 4.2(4)]}
    \hline\hline
\hphantom{XX}F
            & \hphantom{XXx}R        \\
\hline
 42.34(16)  &   42.34(16)           \\
424.34(16)  & 5542.34(5016)         \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 4.2]
                S[table-format = 5.2]}
21.9        &   20.8                \\
 9.1        &    8.7                \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to center it? I mean that \pm and decimal point will be under the R?

Comment: What means the number in () please? table-format = 3.2(3)

Comment: number of digits present uncertainty. i.e  part of number after `pm` symbol. For more details please read `siunitx` documentation.

Comment: Thank you and the centering?

Comment: Which centering? In my MWE it is not used anywhere ...

Comment: |I would like to give \pm and decimal point to the center. Is it possible?

Comment: @LukášAltman, both can't be centered at same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98193/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-zarko).

Comment: This may already have been settled, but I think that the wish is for the "F" and "R" in the column headings to be positioned  directly above the `\pm`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I must confess, that now I don't understand what is OP problem. Addendum is based on OP comments provided me in chat room.

Comment: The "already settled" was my way of saying that I hadn't read the  separate chat discussion.  I think you've got it now (except that the "F" is just a smidge farther to the right than it might be).

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I don't liked my solution very much :-(, it require manual tweaking which is not accurate. Also probably I didn't understood OP correctly. I will left answer as it is.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Zarko How to do manual tweaks for position of the column header? I tried another table and I am not able to tweek it. Thank you

Comment: @LukášAltman, huh is a while ago ... i suspect that you mean a second example. There are letters F and R moved with use of `\hpantom{...}` where ˙...` is determined by estimation and trial for how many letters X and x should be moved. For the first example aligning is straightforward using `siunitx` features. For more you should show your new problem, the best is as new question.

Comment: Thank you I created a new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509117/table-next-to-table-and-their-align

Answer (score 3):

This may alternatively be done fairly simply using the `dcolumn` package, and then some spacing adjustments. The new column type defined here centers on the `+` but prints `\pm`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{table}
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{D{+}{\,\pm\,}{#1}} % see dcolumn documentation, page 2

\begin{tabular}{e{6.4}e{7.5}}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{R} \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
42.34+0.16  &   42.34+0.16   \\
424.34+0.16 & 5542.34+50.16  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
21.9            &   20.8      \\
9.1             &   8.7       \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some of the prior comments requested further centering of the heading and the decimal in the next rows. To cover the headings, one way is to make numbers in the newcolumn type symmetric, so that the `\pm` is in the center of the column.  To deal with the decimal numbers below, we can add a phantom character to bring the decimal to the center of the column.

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{table}
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{D{+}{\,\pm\,}{#1}} % see dcolumn documentation, page 2

\begin{tabular}{e{6.6}e{7.7}} % These only need to be 6.4 and 7.5, but making the 6.6 and 7.7 (symmetric) centers F and R on pm.
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{R} \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
42.34+0.16  &   42.34+0.16   \\
424.34+0.16 & 5542.34+50.16  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{21.9\phantom{9}}  &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{20.8\phantom{9}} \\ % <== add phantom character to make the decimal centered
\multicolumn{1}{c}{9.1}              &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.7}              \\% <== add phantom character to make the decimal centered
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it's great solution

Comment: Glad that it worked well for you!

Comment: One of a nice reply...