# Align in two tables

Tags: tables

What provide that point and `\pm` are aligned in this code ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506660/how-to-align-values-in-table-according-to-the-pm-and-point/506742?noredirect=1#comment1280767_506742))?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         table-column-width=6em}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 3.2(3)]
                S[table-format = 4.2(4)]}
    \hline\hline
\hphantom{XX}F
            & \hphantom{XXx}R        \\
\hline
 42.34(16)  &   42.34(16)           \\
424.34(16)  & 5542.34(5016)         \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 4.2]
                S[table-format = 5.2]}
21.9        &   20.8                \\
 9.1        &    8.7                \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried it and the result was wrong.

[image]

**EDIT**

Code with mistakes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\Rnom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{R}^{\rm N}_\odot$}}
\newcommand{\Mnom}{\hbox{$\mathcal{M}^{\rm N}_\odot$}}
\newcommand{\st}{$^\circ$}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} 
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         table-column-width=10em}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = 3.2(3)]
                S[table-format = 1.2(3)]}
    \hline\hline
ADFJHFK   &AGHDFG & FDJDFH     \\
\hline
$a$ (\Rnom)                   &  41.91(18)  &   40.71(21)        \\
$\omega$ (\st)                & 148.73(149) &       158.37(71)        \\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = 2.3]
                S[table-format = 2.3]}
$M_1$ (\Mnom)  &    21.1    &   19.4  \\
$M_2$ (\Mnom)  &    8.8     &   8.1   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: The `e` column type is declared to be centred on  `±`, and  in the below (centred) cells,   numbers have the same number of digits on each side of the decimal dot, adding phantom digits if necessary.

Comment: What is `e` column?

Comment: Itis not a stanard type. It is defined in the answer you linked to (`\newcolumntype{e}{…}`).

Comment: Oh, yes, that answer worked. And Zarko's second answer? I have problem with his answer.

Comment: That was John's answer. As to to Zarko's second answer, he cheated on the number of digits for the second table, taking into account that by default, an `S` column is centred on the decimal dot.

Comment: What is wrong with code I added to my quetion please? And why is not possible to write more letters instead of R anf F in Zarko's answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98878/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-bernard).