# Table next to table and their align

Tags: tables

I have code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Solution}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} 
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,table-column-width=6em}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = 3.2(3)]
                S[table-format = 1.2(3)]}
    \hline\hline
{GJH}   &{JHG} & {KJH}  \\
\hline
GGG                  &      75.91(18)       &       77.71(21)      \\  
GHJ               & 122.73(159)     &       452.37(71)     \\
GHGKJ               &   21.96(33)       &       77.28(25)     \\
JGKJ                    &   78.1(3)         &       54.6(4)       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = 2.3,table-space-text-post=\hspace{3.8em}]
                S[table-format = 2.3,table-space-text-post=\hspace{4.7em}]@{\hskip -0.66em}}
JHI                             &   21.1        &   19.4    \\
GKJK                            &   8.8         &   8.1     \\
JHGK                            &   13.6        &   10.4    \\
JHGK                            &   3.7         &   1.71    \\
JKGHJ                           &   -8.28       &  -7.69    \\
GKJ                             &   -4.55       &  -2.87    \\
GKJH                        &   0.690       &   0.712   \\
JGK                         &   0.037       &   0.014   \\
JHGK                        &   3.50        &   3.70    \\
GKJ                         &   4.24        &   4.88    \\
JHK                         &  11.389       &   1.008   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline\hline
{GDHDG}         &   {Values}    \\
\hline
HJGJH                       &   1.665656    \\
JKG     &   0.789456    \\
JGK                 &   0.45655     \\
JK                      &   0.45456     \\
JHGJ    &   78956       \\
GJKHG   &   66589       \\
HFJFGH      &   7.454       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}      
    \end{document}
```

How to align tables to have double hline in the same height?

Comment: Could you please explain " but when I delete % in comments, there aren't two tables. "?

Comment: I mean when it is not a comment. Without these two lines - there are two tables and with these lines tables are under.

Comment: With the two lines commented in, I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4fHW.png Is this what you mean? Probably a sketch of your desired output would help.

Comment: I am sorry, I got different output before. Now I have the same as you. So my question is how to shift the right table above to align double hlines. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may liked ...

Tables with `[t]` position option are nested in a table with `p` column type. Beside this, some effort is given to horizontal centering (as you ask in comment below my answer on your previous question) and used are rules from `booktabs` answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Solution}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,table-column-width=7em}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft} p{0.60\linewidth} 
                    >{\raggedright}p{0.35\linewidth}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l S[table-format = 3.2(3)]
                  S[table-format = 3.2(3)]}
    \toprule
GJH         & \hphantom{x}{JHG} & \hphantom{x}{KJH}       \\
    \midrule
GGG         &  75.91(18)        &   77.71(21)   \\
GHJ         & 122.73(159)       &  452.37(71)   \\
GHGKJ       &  21.96(33)        &   77.28(25)   \\
JGKJ        &  78.1(3)          &    4.6(4)     \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = 6.3]
                 S[table-format = 6.3]
                 }
JHI         &   21.1            &   19.4        \\
GKJK        &   8.8             &   8.1         \\
JHGK        &   13.6            &   10.4        \\
JHGK        &   3.7             &   1.71        \\
JKGHJ       &   -8.28           &  -7.69        \\
GKJ         &   -4.55           &  -2.87        \\
GKJH        &   0.690           &   0.712       \\
JGK         &   0.037           &   0.014       \\
JHGK        &   3.50            &   3.70        \\
GKJ         &   4.24            &   4.88        \\
JHK         &  11.389           &   1.008       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}    
        &
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    \toprule
GDHDG       &   Values      \\
    \midrule
HJGJH       &   1.665656    \\
JKG         &   0.789456    \\
JGK         &   0.45655     \\
JK          &   0.45456     \\
JHGJ        &   78956       \\
GJKHG       &   66589       \\
HFJFGH      &   7.454       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the two `tabulars` in `t`op aligned `minipages` you can achieve the following layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}a
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Solution}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} 
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,table-column-width=6em}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.57\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format = 3.2(3)]
                S[table-format = 3.2(2)]}
    \hline\hline
{GJH}   &{JHG} & {KJH}  \\
\hline
GGG                 &      75.91(18)    &       77.71(21)      \\  
GHJ                 & 122.73(159)       &       452.37(71)     \\
GHGKJ               &   21.96(33)       &       77.28(25)     \\
JGKJ                &   78.1(3)         &       54.6(4)       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format = -2.3]
                S[table-format = -2.3]}
JHI                         &   21.1        &   19.4    \\
GKJK                        &   8.8         &   8.1     \\
JHGK                        &   13.6        &   10.4    \\
JHGK                        &   3.7         &   1.71    \\
JKGHJ                       &   -8.28       &  -7.69    \\
GKJ                         &   -4.55       &  -2.87    \\
GKJH                        &   0.690       &   0.712   \\
JGK                         &   0.037       &   0.014   \\
JHGK                        &   3.50        &   3.70    \\
GKJ                         &   4.24        &   4.88    \\
JHK                         &  11.389       &   1.008   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
\hline\hline
{GDHDG}        &   {Values}    \\
\hline
HJGJH          &   1.665656    \\
JKG            &   0.789456    \\
JGK            &   0.45655     \\
JK             &   0.45456     \\
JHGJ           &   78956       \\
GJKHG          &   66589       \\
HFJFGH         &   7.454       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
    \end{table}      
    \end{document}
```

Side note: I have also slightly changed the `table-format` option of some of the `S` type cells in order to get rid of the numerous overfull box warnings.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do a better job of aligning the columns.  Unfortunately, the decimals of some align to the start of the `\pm` of others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Solution}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} 
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,table-column-width=6em}
\begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format = -2.3]
                S[table-format = -2.3]}
    \hline\hline
{GJH}   &{JHG} & {KJH}  \\
\hline
GGG    & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format = 3.2(3)]}{75.91(18)}
       & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format = 3.2(2)]}{77.71(21)}     \\  
GHJ    & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format = 3.2(3)]}{122.73(159)}
       & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format = 3.2(2)]}{452.37(71)}    \\
GHGKJ  & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format = 3.2(3)]}{21.96(33)}
       & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format = 3.2(2)]}{77.28(25)}     \\
JGKJ   & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format = 3.2(3)]}{78.1(3)}
       & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format = 3.2(2)]}{54.6(4)}       \\
\hline
JHI                         &   21.1        &   19.4    \\
GKJK                        &   8.8         &   8.1     \\
JHGK                        &   13.6        &   10.4    \\
JHGK                        &   3.7         &   1.71    \\
JKGHJ                       &   -8.28       &  -7.69    \\
GKJ                         &   -4.55       &  -2.87    \\
GKJH                        &   0.690       &   0.712   \\
JGK                         &   0.037       &   0.014   \\
JHGK                        &   3.50        &   3.70    \\
GKJ                         &   4.24        &   4.88    \\
JHK                         &  11.389       &   1.008   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
\hline\hline
{GDHDG}        &   {Values}    \\
\hline
HJGJH          &   1.665656    \\
JKG            &   0.789456    \\
JGK            &   0.45655     \\
JK             &   0.45456     \\
JHGJ           &   78956       \\
GJKHG          &   66589       \\
HFJFGH         &   7.454       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}      
\end{document}
```